# How to prepare mapping table with large data efficiently using Java

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, db2

Consider the scenario that I have two tables, `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`. I want to create a third table `TABLE_C` which is just a mapping table contains two columns, primary key of `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` . TABLE_A and TABLE_B contains 80 million and 150 million records respectively. Currently I have written one stored procedure in DB2  (That is my DB) which will first join and select the records from both tables and iterate using a cursor. During this iteration I'm inserting in to third table and doing a intermediate commit.

Now this stored procedure is running long time (approx 5Hrs) to complete this since multi row insertion is not possible in DB2 stored procedure (Thats what  I understood). Is it okay to move this in to Java by fetching the records once and insert from Java using JDBC Batch so that Insertion will work in multi row. But how can hold such a large result set in Java without getting OutOfMemoryError

Can somebody suggest best approach.

UPDATED:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE  SESSION.TABLE_DGTT AS (
    select a.type_id as type_id,
            a.a_id as a_id,
           b.b_id as b_id
    from TABLE_A a
    inner join TABLE_B b on
    AND b.process_date = i_order_date
    AND b.tgt_date = CASE WHEN 
             a.tgt_date < i_order_date 
             THEN i_order_date ELSE a.tgt_date END
    where not exists ( select 1 from TABLE_C c where 
    a.type_id = c.type_id
    AND a.a_id = c.a_id) 
    AND a.process_date <= i_order_date  
    )                                      
    WITH NO DATA NOT LOGGED ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;  
    
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM SESSION.TABLE_DGTT;
    
    LOAD FROM C1 OF CURSOR INSERT INTO TABLE_C NONRECOVERABLE;
```

Comment: Side notes: your `CASE` is a simple `MAX(a.tgt_date, i_order_date)`.  A good chunk of the time taken in making the DGTT is going to be the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause - if you're doing this as a one-time load, you should be able to just run this as a straight `INSERT` (into `TABLE_C`) statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid row by row processing completely because it is always significantly slower than the alternative set based approach for this kind of problem.

You should find that doing things inside the database , using unlogged techniques where possible, is the fastest method, if speed is the most important consideration. But sometimes other considerations are more important than speed.

Consider altering your stored procedure, to use a set based approach.

If a single query (multi-table join) is enough to specify the **final** result set (for your `table_C`, then you do not need any staging tables, and you can consider **either** using an unlogged load to populate the final table (see below) or plain logged insert.

If the processing requires one or more staging table to create the final result-set, one option is to create one or more `not logged` DGTT (declare global temporary table) in the stored-procedure, whose structure matches the final table (TABLE_C in your question). You can use `on commit preserve rows` for the DGTT if multiple units of work are necessary to populate it (i.e multiple `insert`, `update`, `delete`, `merge` statements are needed).

Then populate that session table using SQL, avoiding row-by-row processing (don't use cursors for populating the DGTT, use set processing such as `insert into session.xxxx (...) select...` , or `merge` etc. ). You can use as many statements are needed to populate the session table and commit as needed to release any locks.

Compress the DGTT if that is appropriate.  Partition the DGTT (by hash) if that is appropriate.  Dynamically index the DGTT if that is appropriate and runstats it. All these are possible inside the stored procedure.

When you are satisfied that the DGTT contents are correct, you are ready to populate the final table.

Remember, you only need a DGTT if you really need to **stage** the result set or do additional processing or verifications before writing the final table (table_c) in your example.

To populate the final table (either from original source tables with a single multi-table join,  or from a DGTT on which you've done whatever processing is required), you can **either** use the unlogged `load` command via the ADMIN_CMD stored procedure (if your Db2-server platform supports this function), or you can use the (much slower) `INSERT INTO TABLE_C(...) SELECT ... FROM...` . With a logged insert, depending on the available capacity of your transaction-logs, you may need to batch this step.

To use `load` ( via  **admin_cmd()** ) requires careful thought and planning, and requires comprehension of the issues and trade offs involved, so study the documentation carefully or engage an experienced programmer to do the work.

This solution requires programming skill and competence and experience.

Comment: Two doubts; You said 'Then populate that table using SQL, avoiding row-by-row processing.' how to avoid row by row processing? Second, From DGTT again im populating using cursor which will insert in to TableC as it in my existing SP ?

Comment: Clarifications added.

Comment: Populating to DGTT using 'insert into' method should be done in multiple sets right? But How is it possible Do you have any link/reference as example please

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Have you never worked with unlogged DGTT inside sprocs? Define your DGTT as unlogged , and `on commit preserve rows` and you can insert/update/delete/merge as often as you want in the sproc, with as many commits are make sense for the isolation-level. Why would you need a reference for that?

Comment: Sorry I'm not database expert. Once I declare DGTT, how will I use insert into session.xxxx (...) select... in multiple batches since I'm doing inside stored procedure.

Comment: inside the sproc body, you must have the `declare global temporary table session.somename(...) with replace not logged on commit preserve rows`, and you can then, in the same block , insert into that table as if it was an ordinary table. You can also create indexes on the dgtt, and runstats (all inside the sproc) it if that gives an advantage depending on your SQL.

Comment: i believe I cannot insert millions of records in to DGTT without having intermediate commit. I still didnt get how to populate data to DGTT in batches.

Comment: Once the DGTT is `not logged`, and `on commit preserve rows`, you can insert *billions* of rows into a DGTT (especially if you have the hardware/software to `distribute by hash`), and use as many commits , and as many insert/update/delete/merge as you like.

Comment: So, with single session.xxxx (...) select statement (without any batch logic) all the data can be populated ?!!

Comment: Which part of my previous comment have you not understood?

Comment: I have added my sproc body in the question. Is this what you suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to try [LOAD command using the ADMIN_CMD procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023577.html) using cursor based on SELECT statement using your source tables. It's suitable for large data loads.
Use `NONRECOVERABLE` option, if you are not familiar with LOAD utility. And it's better to read about the LOAD options to understand the side effects.